# the obj should have been destroyed at the end of function call 'f'

Tags: c++

the obj should have been destroyed at the end of function call 'f', the object returned should have been a new object. I should have got the "Destroying" message twice.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class c{
    int i;
public:
    ~c(){cout<<"Destroying"<<endl;}
    c(){cout<<"Constructing"<<endl;}
    c(const c &a){cout<<"Copy Constructing"<<endl;}
    int get_i(){cout<<i<<endl;return i;}
    void set_i(int i){this->i=i;}
};

c f(){
    c obj;
    obj.set_i(1);
    return obj;
}
int main() {
    f().get_i();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get 1 "Destroying" printout in release-mode and 2 "Destroying" printouts in debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

This is named return value optimization (NRVO). It is an optimization to remove unnecessary copies of objects. The object `obj` is being constructed directly in the return value of the function.

The elision of copies is explicitly allowed in a few circumstances, including:

> in a return statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object (other than a function or catch-clause parameter) with the same cv-unqualified type as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the automatic object directly into the function’s return value